# Download statistics for a remote file

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

The issue I am struggling with now is the following. I have a zip archive on a remote server. The eclipse plug-in I have developed downloads this archive using the suggestion from this forum:

```
//Connect readable channel to the URL
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(libraryUrl.openStream());
//Create local file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(libraryZipPath);
//Download the remote archive to the local file
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, libraryUrl.openConnection().getContentLength()); 
//Close channel
fos.close();
```

I have an html file at the server that counts visit statistics for the web-page. The javascript that does counting is as follows:

```
var data = '&r=' + escape(document.referrer) + '&n=' + escape(navigator.userAgent)
+ '&p=' + escape(navigator.userAgent) + '&g=' + escape(document.location.href);
if (navigator.userAgent.substring(0,1)>'3')
data = data + '&sd=' + screen.colorDepth + '&sw=' + escape(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);

document.write('<a href="http://www.1freecounter.com/stats.php?i=89959" target=\"_blank\">');
document.write('<img alt="Free Counter" border=0 hspace=0 '+'vspace=0 src="http://www.1freecounter.com/counter.php?i=89959' + data + '">');
document.write('</a>');
```

The question is: Is it somehow possible to use this javascript or html file with it to count the download statistics for the archive file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the reply, Philipp!

I have figured out how to make it work in a very simple way. Let us consider a counter in the example above ("http://www.1freecounter.com/stats.php?i=89959"). The counter by that address  takes 6 parameters in total:

r - document referrer,

n and p are user agent, which consists of a browser name, OS name, OS ver, browser ver etc.,

g is the location,

sd and sw are the colour depth and the screen size (we can skip these two for a binary file).

Then, we form a string for a counting request. For instance,

```
String cntURL = "http://www.1freecounter.com/counter.php?i=89959&r="+
URLEncoder.encode("some string for a referrer","UTF-8") + "&n="+
URLEncoder.encode("browser name (OS name OS version) browser version", "UTF-8")+"&p="+
URLEncoder.encode("the same as above", "UTF-8")+"&g=<location string>";
```

Notice that the parameters are encoded into utf-8 character set. Otherwise, the counter will not count the access properly.

Then, simply using URL class, we create an URL object and open a steam:

```
URL statsUrl = new URL(cntURL);
statsUrl.openStream();
```

That is it! There is no need to research what parameters are in http header. It is simply a matter of forming a proper string to which to open a connection.

I have written a simple method that retrieves all info required for the request and have inserted a call to it in a method where I download the file from a server.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a third party webcounter which is embedded as a graphic in your website. When the users browser loads this graphic, the third party server notices the access and increments the counter.

This doesn't work for binary downloads, because when a binary file is downloaded, the webcounter graphic isn't requested.

What you could try is to make your Java program also download the counter graphic when it downloads the binary file. Make sure to pass the URL of the zip archive as Referrer HTTP header to the image download so that the script on the server counts it as access to it. You will have to use the URLConnection class in order to set custom HTTP headers like Referrer.